Chartjs > Display tooltip on two charts when hovered over anyone of the chart
on Hover tooltip works for one chart at a time, it should display tooltip on both the charts. The second chart does displays active points but not the tooltip. The tooltip is a custom one used here.
const lineChartOptions: ChartOptions<"line"> = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    interaction: {
      mode: "index",
      intersect: false,
    },
    onHover: handleHover,
    plugins: {
      crosshair: {
        value: 10, // Adjust this value as needed
        line: {
          color: "red", // crosshair line color
          width: 1, // crosshair line width
        },
        sync: {
          enabled: true, // enable trace line syncing with other charts
          group: 1, // chart group
          // suppressTooltips: false, // suppress tooltips when showing a synced tracer
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        position: "nearest", 
        enabled: false, // Disable the default tooltip
        external: customTooltip, // Enable custom tooltip
        callbacks: {
          beforeTitle: function (context) {
            // return[context.parsed.y]
            return [`${context[0].label}`];
          },
          label: function (context) {
            console.log(context);
            if (context.datasetIndex === 0) {
              return `<div class="flex flex-col">
                      <div class="flex items-center mt-1">
                        <div class="w-2 h-2 bg-[#8C94BD] rounded-full mr-2"></div>
                        <div class="block text-[#8C94BD]">$${context.parsed.y} <span class='text-black pl-2'>${context.dataset.label}</span></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>`;
            }
            if (context.datasetIndex === 1) {
              return `<div class="flex flex-col">
                      <div class="flex items-center mt-1">
                        <div class="w-2 h-2 bg-[#C3C34B] rounded-full mr-2"></div>
                        <div class="block text-[#C3C34B]">$${context.parsed.y} <span class='text-black pl-2'>${context.dataset.label}</span></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>`;
            }
            return context.label;
          },
          title: function (context) {
            //Display month and year
            // return context[0].label;
          },
        },
      },
    },

    scales: {
      x: {
        border: {
          dash: [4, 8],
          width: 0,
        },

        ticks: {
          callback: function (val: any) {
            // Hide every 2nd tick label
            const label = this.getLabelForValue(val);
            if (label[0] === "Jul") {
              const year = label[1]; // Since label is in the format [month, year]
              return year;
            }
            return null;
          },
        },
        offset: true, // This will extend the line chart beyond the data points
        // display: false
        grid: {
          display: true, // Hides/show X-axis gridlines
        },
      },
      y: {
        // offset: true,
        border: {
          dash: [4, 8],
          width: 0,
        },
        //to start with 0 tick
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          maxTicksLimit: 6,
          callback: function (value) {
            return "$" + value;
          },
        },
        grid: {
          display: true, // Hide/Shows Y-axis gridlines
        },
      },
    },
  };

<Line id="chart1" data={data} options={lineChartOptions} />
<Line id="chart2" data={data} options={lineChartOptions} />

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TQ7XYMTr7t4
This is exactly what needs to be achieved but how can it be done the same in nextjs

Please add a [mcve] so we can tinker with your existing code to help you further.
